# Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported In Nestjs Unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, nestjs

I want to do unit testing of service in nestjs using mongoose.
This error comes up at the end

> Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously.

> Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.

[image]

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { closeInMongodConnection, rootMongooseTestModule } from '../test-utils/mongo/MongooseTestModule';
import { UserSchema } from './user.model';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

describe('UserController', async () => {
  let controller: UsersController;
  let service: UsersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [rootMongooseTestModule(), MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }])],
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [UsersService],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should return all the events', async () => {
    const result = {
      totalDocs: 0,
      resource: [],
    };

    const data = await service.findAll();
    expect(data).toEqual(result);
  });
  

  afterAll(async () => {
    await closeInMongodConnection();
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please may you fix the editing in the question? There seems to be a snippet nested inside a code block?

Answer (score 1):

[Jest](https://jestjs.io) (not Nest) doesn't support returning a promise from the `describe` callback. You can have asynchronous tests, but the test suite (the `describe` block) needs to be synchronous. Remove the `async` from your top level `describe` block.

Comment: In my code, creating the initial state (used in each test) requires an async request. Do I just need to re-establish that state on each test? Is there no way to do an async setup outside of a test?

Comment: Why not make use of `beforeEach` or `beforeAll` which can be `async` and ran before the test(s)